# Insert <img> from custom string markup within Blazor

Tags: c#, html, data-binding, blazor, blazor-client-side

I'm trying to create a custom string markup to use within JSON data that produces an inline icon when rendered within a Blazor component.

So the JSON data might look something like this:

```
[
   {
      "name": "Banana"
      "description": "This item is a {fruit.png}fruit."
   }
]
```

And I would like the {fruit.png} portion to render as an image within a specific folder. Almost as if it were being rendered as such in HTML

```
<h2>Banana</h2>
<div>This item is a <img src='/images/icons/fruit.png'/>fruit.</div>
```

I could write the JSON data in HTML syntax and bind the data as such

```
<h2>@item.Name</h2>
<div>@((MarkupString)@item.Description)</div>
```

But that introduces possible security isses by rendering as raw HTML. I would much prefer a way to do that, but only allow custom image blocks that pull from a specific folder. That way it's impossible to inject malicious code into the JSON file.

Any ideas? Thanks!